# Git loses tracking randomly

Tags: git, git-bash

I have a problem for two weeks with git, more precisely with git for windows (Git-2.36.1-64).

This is very strange behaviour, cause randomly (for me it's randomly) git loses tracking of files. What I mean, that I modify 10 files, and when I commit, it will commit 7 files, but forgets 3 another files. Then I have to run two commands: "git rm --cached . -r" and "git reset ." and this commands always help me. Sometimes it keeps all files for 2 hours, sometimes forgets all files.
"git status" command shows that repo is clean, nothing is in stage or unstage mode. Even I modify file... Sometimes it keep files, sometimes not. It is not problem with console, VS Code or Visual Studio same problem, just loses tracking.

Unfortunately, this happens with all repositories. Reinstalling git or using git portable did not help. I also used "Reset PC" in Windows but keep my files, it removed env variables etc. Also did not help.

I am 100% sure that those repos are ok, cause my collegues use the same repos from our Azure DevOps. I also used this repos on my second computer and never had problem like this.

I am run out of ideas and this is very disturb my daily work...

About Windows, I am using newest version of Windows 11. Maybe this is the problem?

EDIT: Today it happened again, so I can show what is happening.
[image: File being modified but not saved yet]
[image: Filed saved and dissapered from changes]
[image: Git status also shows working tree clean]
[image: Run Git rm --cached . -r and git reset .]
[image: Now git tracks the file]

1. File being modified but not saved yet

2. Filed saved and dissapered from changes

3. Git status also shows working tree clean

4. Run Git rm --cached . -r and git reset .

5. Now git tracks the file

Comment: blind guess : is your local repository located in a directory that is managed by some cloud syncing service ? (ownCloud / iCloud / googleDrive ...)

Comment: @LeGEC No, repo is not on a shared drive. Maybe the problem is with some gpo or some helpdesk stuff. This is laptop in domain, but I working from home. I see that is complex problem, so probably I have to drive to company and reinstall whole windows...

Comment: This is probably going to be complicated to debug. You might want to use `git ls-files --debug` to capture the index contents before and after the oddness, and/or copy the `.git/index` file before and after to see if it has changed. You may want to fuss with whether Git's file system monitoring software is running.

Comment: (edited my previous suggestion, `git ls-files --debug` is more explicit about flags) can you run `git ls-files --debug | grep -B5 "flags: [^0]"` to see if you have weird flags (e.g: `assume-unchanged` or `skip-worktree`) set in your local repo ?

Comment: Ok so I run git ls-files --debug | grep -B5 "flags: [^0]" and seems to be a good lead.

Some files have "flags: 0" but other "flags: 8000". Files with flags:0 act normally git tracks them. But those with flags:8000 after modify and save git does not see.

Comment: I am also see that this flags change after "git commit". For example i change two files, then commit them. Then I want to modify same files again and git does not track them, but other than those two are ok. 

Funny things happen when I change file save it and ctrl+z the change and save git behave strange. I run git status and says that working tree clean. I try to change branch and says I can't "commit your changes". I check flags still 8000. Then I run rm --cached and reset. Still nothing to commit cause I ctrl+z but can change the branch.

Link to screenshots: next comment

Comment: [1 screen](https://postimg.cc/nMNQGQnr)
[2 screen](https://postimg.cc/B8DqstdY)
[3 screen](https://postimg.cc/nsd1FcBm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[edit] This answer first suggested an issue with a file syncing service, but after further debugging, it looks like your issue is linked to some flags set in your local repository :

running `git ls-files --debug | grep -B5 "flags: [^0]"` you established that some files had the [`assume-unchanged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---no-assume-unchanged) flag set (displayed as `flags: 8000`).

You can read the [Using assume unchanged bit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit) section of [`git help update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) for more details (or for a good headache ;) ).

Here is the command to remove that flag from one individual file :

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <filepath>
```

There is a shorter way to get the complete list of `assume-unchanged` files :

```
git ls-files -v | grep "^[a-z]"   # see 'git help ls-files' :
                                  # status is lowercase if assume-unchanged

# to "un assume unchange" all files in one go :
git ls-files -v | grep "^[a-z]" | awk '{ print $2 }' |\
    xargs git update-index --no-assume-unchanged
```

---

Also check the `core.ignorestat` config value: it should be set to false (or you should be aware of a good reason to keep it to true)

```
git config core.ignorestat
```

Some other configuration variables affect how `git` deals with its index, they all start with `core.` (read `git help update-index` and search for `core.` to list them) :

```
git config --show-origin --get-regexp core

# config variables to look for (2022-05-31 - git version 2.35.0) :
#   core.filemode
#   core.fsmonitor
#   core.ignorestat
#   core.splitIndex
#   core.symlinks
#   core.trustctime
#   core.untrackedCache
```

Comment: It would be nice if that was a problem. But nothing syncs in the background. As I wrote, I did a reset, which literally uninstalled all applications and now I installed the minimum needed to work.

Comment: Ok. so running git config --global core.ignorestat returns true. So i change it to false

Comment: well we've zeroed on your issue ( I think :D ). Out of curiosity : do you remember setting this config value yourself ?

Comment: Hmm probably when I had another problem with git. It worked very very slow. And I think just with not full consciousness just copied some stackoverflow advices to enhance git and maybe than? But now after "Reset PC", git works preety fast but configs could remain.

Comment: After changing this flag core.ignorestat I cannot reproduce the problem which I described in comment above. So thank you very much, I hope it doesn't come back.

About the git config --show-origin --get-regexp core

it returns

file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.autocrlf true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.fscache true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.symlinks false