# Git Checkout <branch> has immediate changes

Tags: git

I have cloned a repo from Azure DevOps. (Everything is done through git CLI). When I checkout a specific branch (lets call it master2) everything checks out ok, but then there is an IMMEDIATE unstaged file. I cannot restore it. I cannot stash it easily. I basically have to force checkout out of master2. What is happening?

Comment: Can you provide any more information? There isn't much to go on here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437939/git-loses-tracking-randomly

Comment: @JimRedmond You're right. i should have provided some context around which file was conflicted, and some other clues. For example the file was linkedService_new.json which was showing as having changes immediately after checkout. It looks like it was interpreting changes from the file linkedServices_New.json (notice the caps.) fixed directly in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. It seems that a file with the same name, though different case (ie _new and _New) seemed to be the culprit. I renamed the _New to _old and it seemed to resolve the issue with the naming conflicts). I just inherited this repo and some interesting stuff going on.